# Ошибка: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Pacman
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[,] map = ReadMap("map.txt.txt");
            DrawMap(map);
        }
        private static char[,] ReadMap(string path)
        {
            string[] file = File.ReadAllLines("map.txt.txt");

            char[,] map = new char[GetMaxLengthOfline(file), file.Length];

            for (int x = 0; x < map.GetLength(0); x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(1); y++)
                    map[x, y] = file[y][x];
            return map;
                
        }
        private static void DrawMap(char[,] map)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
               for (int x = 0; x < map.GetLength(0); x++) 
                { 
                    Console.Write(map[x, y]);
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
        private static int GetMaxLengthOfline(string[] lines)
        {
            int maxLength = lines[0].Length;

            foreach (string line in lines)
                 if (line.Length > maxLength) 
                    maxLength = line.Length;

            return maxLength;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Форматирование сбилось, и на какой строке ошибка возникает?

Answer (score 0):

В каждой строке разное количество символов, а вы идете в цикле до индекса максимальной длины строки. Ошибка вот тут:

```
file[y][x]
```

Comment: А как исправить ее

Comment: @AzeRoN объясните, что вы пытаетесь сделать, я исправлю ответ

Comment: Я уже сделал, спасибо